# Invariant Factors vs. Elementary Divisors

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-theory

I have been studying Cooperstein's Advanced Linear Algebra for about seven months now and I am having problems understanding how to find the elementary divisors of a linear operator and how to find the invariant factors of a linear operator as well.  I feel as though if I'm having trouble with these then I won't be able to move forward.  I understand that the invariant factors comprise the characteristic polynomial and can find them using determinants and eigenvalues (I get that), but the text builds the theory up using direct sums, minimal polynomials of T, and T-cyclic subgroups and I'm just not seeing it.

As for an example, 
Let $T$ be an element of $L(\mathbf R^4,\mathbf R^4)$ be the operator given by
$$
T(v) = \begin{pmatrix} -3&2&2&-4\\-3&1&4&-4\\-2&0&3&-2\\-1&0&2&-1\end{pmatrix}(v)
$$
Determine the elementary divisors and the invariant factors of $T$.

(how do I write the correct matrix in LaTeX?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Smith normal form algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm) on $T - x I$ you find that the *invariant factors* (at least, as I am used to call them) are
$$
1,1,1,x^4 -1.
$$
(In particular minimal polynomial = characteristic polynomial = $x^4 - 1$.)
It follows that over the rationals the *elementary divisors* are
$$
x-1, x+1, x^2 + 1.
$$

**PS** A note on terminology. Wikipedia has the same definitions of [invariant factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor) and [elementary divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_divisors) I am used to. However, in the [article above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Example), the invariant factors are computed, but they are called elementary divisors.

Comment: He assumes that the minimal polynomial of T is p_1(x)^e_1*p_2(x)^e_2*...*p_t(x)^e_t where p_i(x)^e_i are distinct irreducible polynomials.  Then he sets V_i=Ker(p_i(T)^e_i) and supposes that V_i = the direct sum of T-cyclic subspaces generated by vectors v_(i,j) where j = 1..s_i, and where the minimal polynomial of T with respect to v_(i,j) = p_i(x)^f_(i,j) and f_(i,1) >= f_(i,2) >= ... >= f_(i,s_i).  These polynomials are the elementary divisors.

Comment: So basically these things are used to help realize the structure of a Vector space over a field.  So you basically partition a vector space into subspaces that are invariant under the elementary divisors?  Is that the jist here?

Comment: You know, I have to give a crash course on the argument in a few days' time. As I see it, the key point is that if you regard the underlying vector space as a $\mathbf{Q}[x]$-module, where $x$ acts as $T$, then the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID gives you all the information you need about the action of $T$ on $V$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain#Corollaries but I am looking for a better online source. (Jacobson's Basic Algebra I has a good treatment.)

Answer (score 8):

Here  is an algorithm for finding the invariant factors using elementary methods.  First find the minimal polynomial (the largest invariant factor).  This can be done by finding the minimal polynomial of each vector in a basis and finding the least common multiple of of these polynomials.  You can also find a maximal vector, v, whose minimal polynomial WRT the operator is the minimal polynomial of the operator.  Set V' equal to the quotient of the space V by the T-invariant subspace generated by T, .  Let T' be the operator on V' induced by T.  Use the same algorithm to find the minimal polynomial of T'.  This is the next invariant factor.  You can continue in this way to find all the invariant factors without use of the Smith Form (which requires a knowledge of finite generated modules over Principal Ideal Domains (PIDs).

Finding the elementary divisors is problematic since it requires factoring the invariant factors into irreducible polynomials and there is no efficient algorithm for doing this.

Comment: This is a nice answer.  Perhaps however in practice the smith version is equally elementary and also quicker.  I.e. one only needs to use the Euclidean algorithm to diagonalize the characteristic matrix X.I-T, the same computation needed to find an lcm.  The invariants appear on the diagonal.  One does not need any knowledge of the theory of modules over pid's for the calculation, only perhaps to help explain why it works.  The ease of this calculation is not clear from the turgid wikipedia article however, but is quite clear in both Jacobson and Van der Waerden.